# Is it possible to decompose any quantum channel into product channels if allowing negative coefficients?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-entanglement

1. We know that a separable quantum channel (i.e., a trace-preserving and completely positive map) on a bipartite system $A\otimes B$ is defined as: it can be decomposed to convex superposition of product channels
   \begin{align}
   \mathcal{T}(\cdot) = \sum_i{p_i}{\left(\mathcal{T}_i^A\otimes\mathcal{T}_i^B\right)\left(\cdot\right)}
   \end{align}
   with $p_i>0$.
2. Besides, each bipartite quantum state (separable or entangled) can be decomposed as $\rho = \sum q_i\rho_i^A\otimes \rho_i^B$ if negative coefficients $q_i$ are allowed, which is proved as in the following.
   We consider a set of Hermitian, complete, and orthonormal basis $\{O_{\alpha}\}^{A(B)}$ for each operator space of $A$ or $B$.
   The density operator can be expanded with this basis as
   \begin{align}
       \rho = \sum_{\alpha\beta}{r_{\alpha\beta}O_{\alpha}^A\otimes O_{\beta}^B},
   \end{align}
   where each Hermitian operator can be diagonalized
   \begin{align}
       O_{\alpha(\beta)}^{A(B)} = \sum_{i}\lambda_{i}|i\rangle\langle i|,
   \end{align}
   which gives a general decomposition of $\rho$ with product density matrices$|i\rangle\langle i|_{\alpha}\otimes |j\rangle\langle j|_{\beta}$.
3. Then an interesting question arises: Is it possible to decompose any entangled quantum channel to summations of product channels if negative coefficients are allowed?